# Is this correct "Aber mit ihren Sohn, John, konnte er aber nicht."?

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage

Is the following correct?:

*Voldemort, ein gefährlicher Mörder und ein dunkler Magier, hat erfolgreich die Potters, aus irgendeinem Grund, getötet. **Aber mit ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht** und daher ist er sofort verschwunden.*

My teacher said that *"Aber mit ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht."* does not make much sense. But I really think it does!

edit: I don't understand why my question is put on hold as an "off-topic". I got actually my answer!

Comment: The commas around *aus irgendeinem Grund* are not necessary. In German, commas mark a small pause in speech. You don't want to have more pauses than necessary.

Comment: can I avoid using toten again? Like "Ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht"

Comment: Use a synonyms dictionary, e.g. https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/t%C3%B6ten.php or https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/t%C3%B6ten. The generic term is *umbringen*.

Comment: Sorry, how does this answers my question?

Comment: *Ihren Sohn Harry konnte er aber nicht umbringen, und ist daher …* – You cannot skip the complement to *können* in this modal phrase. There are other ways to describe *I didn't work.* without the modal *können*. Take a look into the verbs *schaffen* and *klappen*.

Comment: in english makes sense to say: "but with their son he could not"? or a im being confused?

Comment: i want to link this sentence to the previous one

Comment: That's *Aber mit ihrem Sohn konnte er **das** nicht*. ← The *das* is the shortcut for *das Töten*. It's required. Also, *schaffen* is better than *können* here.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @VladiC4T: 1. *»can I avoid using toten again? Like "Ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht«* - No. You need the full verb. *»Können«* is just a modal verb here, that needs either another verb to modify, or a pronoun. But in your sentence there is non of both. - | - 2. *»in english makes sense to say: "but with their son he could not"? or a im being confused?«* - You have to ask this on a board about English language. This is a board about German language.

Comment: @Janka: »Voldemort hat die Potters getötet. Aber **mit ihrem Sohn** konnte er das nicht.« Was konnte er nicht **mit** Harry? Ihn töten? Welche Funktion genau soll hier das Wort *»mit«* haben? Das ergibt keinen Sinn. Falsch: *»Voldemort tötet **mit** Harry.«* Richtig: *»Voldemort tötet Harry.«* (ohne *»mit«*)

Comment: *Das kannst du mit mir nicht (machen)!* heißt auch nicht, dass ich annehme, dass ich mithelfen solle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mit" can indeed be used in that way. See for example https://www.dwds.de/wb/mit I.4 where it says it means the same as "Was [ihren Sohn, Harry] angeht, so ..."

However, the sentence is not correct as you wrote it:

- The second "aber" is redundant
- you need to state what it is that he couldn't do, i.e. provide an accusative object to "konnte"

  - as a side note, "mit jemandem können" without an accusative object has an [entirely different meaning](https://www.korrekturen.de/synonyme/mit+jemandem+k%C3%B6nnen/): to get along with someone, to like someone
- "mit" requires Dativ

> Aber mit ihre<strike>n</strike>**m** Sohn, Harry, konnte er <strike>aber</strike> **das** nicht

This still feels a bit clumsy to me, though I can't  explain why. To my "sprachgefühl" using "gelingen" instead of "können" makes it smoother:

> Aber mit ihrem Sohn, Harry, gelang ihm das nicht
>
> Aber mit ihrem Sohn, Harry, wollte ihm das nicht gelingen

Comment: exactly this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Side note to the side note: "Du kannst mich mal" is the opposite of getting along with someone

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is right. This sentence doesn't make any sense. If I try to translate it into English I get something like this:

> But together with their son harry, but he couldn't.

I have no idea what you really want to tell, but I think you want to tell, that Voldemort couldn't kill harry. So the preposition *mit* (*together with*) doesn't make any sense. It shouldn't be in this sentence.

And if you want to tell, that he couldn't *kill* harry, you have to say it: The German word for *kill* is *töten.*

And two *aber* in one sentence it too much.

I think (but I'm not really sure) what you wanted to say in english is this:

> But he couldn't kill her son Harry.

So I would suggest one of these sentences:

> 1. Aber ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er nicht töten.
> 2. Ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht töten.

Both are correct, and #1 sounds a little bit better than #2.

Comment: In addition, those commas around Harry are not necessary.

Comment: can I avoid using toten again? Like "Ihren Sohn, Harry, konnte er aber nicht"

Comment: Before reading the context (and automatically reading *ihrem* instead of *ihren*) it actually made sense to me, it was just not the intended sense. Voldemort just did not get along with Harry! :)